# Docx4j consider using Xerces Warning

Tags: java, docx4j

In a Spring MVC server I have this warning every time I use docx4j to generate a docx. The server functions well, but I have a huge log with this warning

```
2022-04-27 18:00:46.241 [http-nio-8080-exec-3] WARN  org.docx4j.XmlUtils - default SAXParserFactory property : null
 Please consider using Xerces.
2022-04-27 18:00:46.248 [http-nio-8080-exec-3] WARN  org.docx4j.XmlUtils - default DocumentBuilderFactory property: null
 Please consider using Xerces.
```

My pom.xml is:

```xml
<!-- Doc4j -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.docx4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>docx4j-JAXB-ReferenceImpl</artifactId>
    <version>8.3.4</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.docx4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>docx4j-core</artifactId>
      <version>8.3.4</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.docx4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>docx4j-export-fo</artifactId>
    <version>8.3.4</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>xerces</groupId>
    <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
    <version>2.12.2</version>
</dependency>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Are you using windows

Comment: Yes I'm using tomcat 9 on windows server 2019

Comment: If this is a WAR deployed to Tomcat, you may need to add Xerces to the Tomcat lib folder instead of deploying it as part of your application (though I'm not 100% sure this will solve the problem).

Answer (score 0):

If you get ...
[main] WARN org.docx4j.XmlUtils - default SAXParserFactory property : null
Please consider using Xerces.
[main] WARN org.docx4j.XmlUtils - default DocumentBuilderFactory property: null
Please consider using Xerces.

... you need xerces on the CP and you need to set the property in docx4j.properties for sax parser to xerces

From docx4j.properties [JAXP factories] section uncomment ... [javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory=com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl]
*** NOTE you will have a different package name for SaxParserFactoryImpl based on the version of xerces

The version of docx4j will have the dependencies needed to be on the CP in /dependencies

if you get ...
[main] WARN org.docx4j.utils.ResourceUtils - Couldn't get resource: docx4j.properties
[main] WARN org.docx4j.Docx4jProperties - Couldn't find/read docx4j.properties; docx4j.properties not found via classloader.

... you have not deployed docx4j.properties - docx4j has defaults, so you first need to deploy docx4j.properties before you can affect those defaults

you need to create (or copy from source ~/resources/) [docx4j.properties]

org.docx4j.Docx4jProperties.java loads docx4j.properties on init() to overwrite the defaults